# How to redirect echo text=1>script.conf

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

From a dos prompt if I lauch the following command

```
echo text=1>script.conf
```

in the script.conf will be written `text=` and not `text=1`
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `>script.conf echo text=1` or `(echo text=1)>script.conf`

Comment: Put a space between `1` and `>`.

Comment: @KenWhite: this will include the space in the file (which might not be a problem in some cases like here (a log file) , but can lead to unexpected behaviour in other cases (when reading the file)).

Comment: @Stephan solution is better, in fact I don't want additional spaces in the generated file.

Answer (score 0):

A number right before `>` is a special syntax where the number is a file descriptor in the C-library sense ([1 is stdout and 2 is stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)).

When cmd.exe sees `>` it will actually remove the number right before `>` (if any) and the filename after it and then execute the remaining text as the command. You are therefore effectively saying; take the stdout result of `echo text=` and write it to the file `script.conf`.

The solution that always works is to reorder it so that the redirection comes first:

```
>script.conf echo text=1
```

If you don't mind an extra space at the end of the line in the file you can do:

```
echo text=1 >script.conf
```

Comment: You're right about the digit left to the `>`, but you'd need to add that the `=`-sign is a standard token separator just like _space_ and _tab_; the issue wouldn't arise when you replace `=` by `_`, for instance…

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stephan I written also a macro based to his solution:

```
@echo on

:: Define LF as a Line Feed (newline) string
set LF=^


::Above 2 blank lines are required - do not remove

::define a newline with line continuation
:: set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^" this is an old style and more complex \n definition
:: Next is the modern style \n definition
(set \n=^^^
%=EMPTY=%
)

set @{CreaPPosEth-Log.properties}=for %%. in (1 2) do if %%.==2 (for %%L in ("!LF!") DO ( %\n%
    set /a "I=1" %\n%
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%1 in ("!args: =%%~L!") do (%\n%
        set "par.!I!=!%%~1!" %\n%
        set /a "I+=1" %\n%
      )%\n%
      %= Inizio della vera macro =% %\n%
      ^>!par.1! echo BillPayment=0%\n%
      ^>^>!par.1! echo GTType=1%\n%
      %= Fine macro =% %\n%
      endlocal %\n%
)) else setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion ^& set args=

set "conf1=.\PPosEth.properties"
%@{CreaPPosEth-Log.properties}% conf1

:ESCI
exit /b 1000
```